# How can I catch a return Value from "Calculate Value" to start another Tool in ArcGis Model builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have troubles with If/else statements in ArcGis Modelbulider. I have imported TauDEM Toolbox to work with D-infinity algorythm. Since D-Infinity only works with .tif raster files
I wanted to check first if the input raster is an .tif raster. After checking I want to start either D-infinity if the return value is true. If it's not, I want to convert it.
For that I tried to use the "Calculate Value" Tool with that code

```
check_if_Tiff("%DGM%")

def check_if_Tiff(DGM):
    import arcpy 
    desc = arcpy.Describe(DGM)
    type = desc.format
    if type == "TIFF":
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"
```

so far so good but I dont know how to catch the return values to use them in another tool.

I have previously read this documentation https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/06/modelbuilderifthenelse1/ but I can't completely follow it. Do I have to do this with a python script or is there a way 
like I am trying?

Comment: Make sure the return value is boolean for calculate value tool, then simply connect it to the other tool as a precondition. This means the tool will only run if calculte value is true, i.e. its a tiff.

Comment: I already tried this but this way only the conversion tool is running if the return value is true. But if its a .tif file it is also supposed to do something. I am looking for something that can also handle the false condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than returning a boolean, how about you modify your code so that it converts your input raster to a .tif and returns that instead..

Something like this:

```py
def check_if_Tiff(DGM,folder):
  import arcpy
  import os
  desc = arcpy.Describe(DGM)
  type = desc.format
  if type == "TIFF":
    return DGM
  else:
    out_r = os.path.join(folder,"{0}.tif".format(os.path.basename(DGM)))
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(DGM,out_r)
   return out_r
```

Comment: This way works just fine and its also shorter. :) Thank you!